# How can i put navigation bar in google login screen?

Tags: ios

Because if user don't want to sign in then there is no way to go back to the previous screen user must need to kill the application.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your `UIWebView` is inside a view controller which has a `UINavigationController`. I suspect that you present your login screen modally (either via a storyboard or programmatically) - try to push it on the navigation stack instead.

EDIT: this is the code I meant, in `QEFilesListViewController`:

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController =
[[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile
                                           clientID:kClientId
                                       clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                   keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                           delegate:self
                                   finishedSelector:finishedSelector];
[self presentViewController:authViewController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

If you change the last statement to

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:authViewController animated:YES];
```

you will get a back button:

[image]

I know that when you press the back button, it will automatically show the login screen again. I figured that if you want to implement this in your own app, you can take appropriate measures to make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: We are just use Google SDK. not display in UIWebView.
Reference URL: https://github.com/googledrive/ios-quickeditor

Answer (score 2):

Try bellow code. This patch solve my proble.

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch controllerWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                                                                                    clientID:GoogleDriveClientID
                                                                                                clientSecret:GoogleDriveClientSecret
                                                                                            keychainItemName:GoogleDriveKeychainItemName
                                                                                           completionHandler:authCompletionHandler];

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:authViewController];
        navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [rootController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
                                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                            target:self
                                                                            action:@selector(didCanceledAuthorization)];
            authViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
            authViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
            authViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Google Drive";
        });
```